# referencing WinSCP COM library from VB6

Tags: vb6, winscp-net

I am trying to use the WinSCP COM library on a old VB6 project I have (it's a legacy application that generates an OCX file, I think we have to use VB6 for it but not 100% sure).

Anyway we want to implement SFTP, and WinSCP can do that readily.

I registered the COM object, and can see the WinSCPNet type library when I go to add the reference.  However I can't see the properties/methods of the classes when I look at the library in the object browser.  Further, this code fails, it does not get to the 3rd MsgBox ("In SendWinSCP4"), it returns from the function at that point, I think because the property UserName is not exposed.

```
MsgBox ("in SendWinSCP")

Dim session As WinSCPnet.session
Dim sessionOptions As WinSCPnet.sessionOptions
Dim transferOptions As WinSCPnet.transferOptions
Set session = New WinSCPnet.session
Set sessionOptions = New WinSCPnet.sessionOptions
Set transferOptions = New WinSCPnet.transferOptions

MsgBox ("in SendWinSCP3")

sessionOptions.Protocol = Protocol_Sftp
sessionOptions.HostName = "example.com"
sessionOptions.UserName = "user"
sessionOptions.Password = "example.com"
sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"

MsgBox ("in SendWinSCP4 " & sessionOptions.HostName & "!")
```

Comment: I was able to get past this by using On Error Resume Next at the top of the sub.  It then shows the 3rd MsgBox and the property, so it looks like all that stuff is being hidden but still works properly.  I can now generate the SFTP call.

Comment: Please consider closing your question.

Answer (score 0):

See above, using On Error Resume Next got me past the error.